# Good Wordpress Theme/plugin for showing off code examples and scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have an ancient version of Wordpress and its WYSIWYG editor really mucks up code examples in my blogs (removing lines and whitespace when saved, etc).

I wish to upgrade and install a theme/plugin that will make it easy to `display code` in a pleasant way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Many sites use Google Code Prettify for syntax highlighting on code, and people have developed wordpress extensions that make it easy to add GCP to a blog. Here's an example of one:

http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/google-code-prettify-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Syntax Highlighter Evolved.
http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

You can use shortcodes like [php] or [css] to contain your source code, and it will be rendered nicely when you view the post/page.

Comment: Believe that's what wordpress.com uses.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/).
From the usage notes:

> Wrap code blocks with <pre
>   lang="LANGUAGE" line="1"> and </pre>
>   where LANGUAGE is a GeSHi supported
>   language syntax. The line attribute is
>   optional.